# How to find and replace only a particular word (which is at the end of the file) using shell command?

Tags: shell, text-processing, sed, awk

File1:

```
Dms 01.01.2015 feeder1 6kv close at 04:30  
Updated  
Dms 01.01.2015 feeder1 6kv open at 06:20  
Updated  
Dms 04.02.2015 feeder10 6kv close at 17:23  
Updated  
Dms 04.02.2015 feeder12 6kv open at 23:30  
Updated  
Dms 12.04.2015 feeder4 6kv disturb at 12:30  
Updated  
Dms 12.04.2015 feeder7 6kv close at 11:09  
Updated  
Dms 16.05.2015 feeder8 6kv open at 13:10  
Updated  
Dms 01.06.2015 feeder3 6kv close at 05:07  
Updated
```

Output will be:

```
Dms 01.01.2015 feeder1 6kv close at 04:30  
Updated  
Dms 01.01.2015 feeder1 6kv open at 06:20  
Updated  
Dms 04.02.2015 feeder10 6kv close at 17:23  
Updated  
Dms 04.02.2015 feeder12 6kv open at 23:30  
Updated  
Dms 12.04.2015 feeder4 6kv disturb at 12:30  
Updated  
Dms 12.04.2015 feeder7 6kv close at 11:09  
Updated  
Dms 16.05.2015 feeder8 6kv open at 13:10  
Updated  
Dms 01.06.2015 feeder3 6kv close at 05:07  
EOF
```

I want to change only the last *Updated* to *EOF* using command.

Please be noted, my line numbers in file is not fixed. It may be 100 lines or may be 500 lines but I want to change only the last word using command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed -e '$s/Updated/EOF/' file
```

Comment: $ means it will update only the last? @cuonglm

Comment: @Nainita: `$` in address match only the last line.

Answer (score 2):

Using Perl:

```
< inputfile perl -0777 -pe 's/Updated$/EOF/'
```